# Can mongoexport accept JavaScript file extension (.js) for the --queryFile option?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Wonder to know if mongoexport --queryFile can accept js files?
If only json then how can cater this query
db.CustomerDocument.aggregate({
$project: {
"_id": 1,
"Country": 1,
"date": {
$toDate: "$CustomerOnlineActiveDate"
}
}
})

The following command runs with errors, due to --queryFile value.

```
mongoexport --uri "mongodb+srv://..." --username myUser --password myPassword  --db CustomerDb --collection Customer --fields _id,Country,date --type csv --queryFile c:\test\FromMongo\AccountConversion.json  --out c:\test\Mini.csv
```

In this mongoexport command if I just delete the --queryFile and its assigned path, it works but the case is that I need the following query be executed.

The text in query file is as below. On mongo shell it can be executed with no issues.

```
db.CustomerDocument.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "Country": 1,
        "date": {
            $toDate: "$CustomerOnlineActiveDate"
        }
    }
})
```

the error I encounter is: *[]' is not valid JSON: invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value.*

As an alternative to this, I created a .json file with the follwoing content:

```
{"$project":{"_id":1,"Country":1,"date":{"$toDate":"$CustomerOnlineActiveDate"}}}
```

and changed accordingly the path to this .json file but still got the following error:

the error I encounter is: *[]' is not valid JSON: invalid character '\' looking for beginning of object key string.*

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a projection where a query filter is expected.

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--queryFile):

> --queryFile=
>
> Specifies the path to a file containing a JSON document as a query filter that limits the documents included in the output of mongodump. --queryFile enables you to create query filters that are too large to fit in your terminal's buffer.

The query filter must be a JSON document, containing [query operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-and-projection-operators).

You might be able to get what you are looking for in 2 steps:

- run the aggregation with the projection and use a `$out` stage to store the result in a temporary collection
- mongoexport from the temporary collection